# Get-ChildItem - Cannot find path

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

Get-ChildItem gets an error when the path is a variable

This works:

```
PS D:\DMH> Get-ChildItem -Path '\\MHRZRSEFS501\F$\NewSkies FileShares\FRBatch$\Test\Test.txt'

Directory: \\MHRZRSEFS501\F$\NewSkies FileShares\FRBatch$\Test


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                                          
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                                          
-a----        5/19/2019   2:45 AM             18 Test.txt
```

But if I put the Path into a variable it doesn't work:

```
PS D:\DMH> $SPath = "'\\MHRZRSEFS501\F$\NewSkies FileShares\FRBatch$\Test\Test.txt'"

Get-ChildItem -Path $SPath

Write-Host "SPath =$SPath" 

Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'D:\DMH\'\MHRZRSEFS501\F$\NewSkies FileShares\FRBatch$\Test\Test.txt'' because it does not exist.
***
SPath ='\\MHRZRSEFS501\F$\NewSkies FileShares\FRBatch$\Test\Test.txt'
```

`D:\DMH\` is obviously the directory where I launched  `PowerShell` from but how did it get in the path for the command?

Comment: If you dont give an absolute path, it will append the path in ur variable to the current working directory. Hence you end up with that. Plust you also have a `\'\\` in your path.

Comment: Modify your path to have a double slash in front to tell the interpreter that its a UNC path. '\\MHRZRSEFS501\F$\NewSkies FileShares\FRBatch$\Test\Test.txt'

Comment: The double slashes are there when I set the variable and in the display after the error message. They're just missing in the error message. Is the first slash being interpreted as an escape character or something?

Answer (score 1):

Double quote ask to PowerShell to evaluate the string. Try this (without double quote):

```
$SPath = '\\MHRZRSEFS501\F$\NewSkies FileShares\FRBatch$\Test\Test.txt'
```

Comment: It worked! I would have bet money against it because of the embedded blank in middle of the path.

Answer (score 0):

This was an absolute nightmare, get-childitem cannot except a string variable if there are multiple paths. Use an array instead.

> Get-ChildItem -Path "\server1\c$\temp", "\server1\d$\temp" -File
> -recurse # works

> $path = '"\server1\c$\temp", "\server1\d$\temp"'; Get-ChildItem -Path "\server1\c$\temp", "\server1\d$\temp" -File
> -recurse # fails with cannot find path

> $path = "'"\server1\c$\temp", "\server1\d$\temp'""; Get-ChildItem -Path "\server1\c$\temp", "\server1\d$\temp" -File
> -recurse # fails with illegal character message (the tick)

Any string that has multiple paths fails, however an array with += as shown below will work.

```
$servers = @("server1", "server2");
$partialPaths = @("\c$\temp\", "\d$\temp\");
foreach ($server in $servers)
    {
        $paths = @();
        foreach ($partialPath in $partialPaths)
        {
            $paths += "\\" + $server + $partialPath;
        }
    }   
Get-ChildItem -Path $paths -File -recurse;
```